# Ksoap2 android library marshal byte[]

Tags: android, web-services, arrays, marshalling, ksoap2

I am trying to pass a byte[] through webservices i need to marshal the byte[]. So far this is what i have. This method is in a class i create called MarshallArray and implements Marshal

```
public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
    byte[] myArray = (byte[]) obj;  
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        writer.startTag("", "ArrayOfBytes");
        writer.text(Base64.encode(myArray[i]).toString());
        writer.endTag("", "ArrayOfBytes");
    }
}
```

The example i used to create this was

```
public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
    String[][][] myArray = (String[][][]) obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        writer.startTag("", "ArrayOfArrayOfString");
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            writer.startTag("", "ArrayOfString");
            for (int k = 0; k < myArray[i][j].length; k++) {
                writer.startTag("", "string");
                writer.text(myArray[i][j][k]);
                writer.endTag("", "string");
            }
            writer.endTag("", "ArrayOfString");
        }
        writer.endTag("", "ArrayOfArrayOfString");
    }
}
```

The problem i have is that in the first method is how to access to the element in byte[] because it can only receive an array and not an element in an byte[]

```
Base64.enconde(byte[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally what I do is that I create a new `SoapObject` as follows:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(...)
```

then I add my byte array as follows:

```
request.addProperty("myArray ", myArray );
```

Then:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Comment: And myArray is a byte[] for example for a image?

Comment: could be, yes i suppose